# No Makefile for target dependency

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, erlang, cowboy

I have code running on my local machine fine. I pull on my Ubuntu server, run `apt-get install erlang` then attempt to `make run` to start my server.

Get an error: erlang.mk:4230: recipe for target 'deps' failed

I try erasing deps folder (it was committed) and rebuilding:

```
ls deps
cowboy  cowlib  jiffy  ranch
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc1-01:~/keystore/sell# rm -rf deps
root@ubuntu-s-2vcpu-4gb-nyc1-01:~/keystore/sell# make run
 DEP    cowboy
 DEP    jiffy
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rmemo,start,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,670}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,122}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ({undef,[{rmemo,start,[],[]},{erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{_},{_}]},{erl_eval,exprs,5,[{_},{_}]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]},{init,do_boot,3,[]}]})

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
make[1]: Entering directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/cowboy'
 DEP    ci.erlang.mk
 DEP    cowlib
 DEP    ranch
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/cowlib'
 DEPEND cowlib.d
 ERLC   cow_base64url.erl cow_cookie.erl cow_date.erl cow_hpack.erl cow_http.erl cow_http2.erl cow_http_hd.erl cow_http_te.erl cow_mimetypes.erl cow_multipart.erl cow_qs.erl cow_spdy.erl cow_sse.erl cow_uri.erl cow_ws.erl
 APP    cowlib
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/cowlib'
make[2]: Entering directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/ranch'
 DEPEND ranch.d
 ERLC   ranch.erl ranch_acceptor.erl ranch_acceptors_sup.erl ranch_app.erl ranch_conns_sup.erl ranch_listener_sup.erl ranch_protocol.erl ranch_server.erl ranch_ssl.erl ranch_sup.erl ranch_tcp.erl ranch_transport.erl
 APP    ranch
make[2]: Leaving directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/ranch'
 DEPEND cowboy.d
 ERLC   cowboy.erl cowboy_app.erl cowboy_bstr.erl cowboy_children.erl cowboy_clear.erl cowboy_clock.erl cowboy_compress_h.erl cowboy_constraints.erl cowboy_handler.erl cowboy_http.erl cowboy_http2.erl cowboy_iolists.erl cowboy_loop.erl cowboy_metrics_h.erl cowboy_middleware.erl cowboy_req.erl cowboy_rest.erl cowboy_router.erl cowboy_static.erl cowboy_stream.erl cowboy_stream_h.erl cowboy_sub_protocol.erl cowboy_sup.erl cowboy_tls.erl cowboy_tracer_h.erl cowboy_websocket.erl
 APP    cowboy
 GEN    rebar.config
make[1]: Leaving directory '/root/keystore/sell/deps/cowboy'
Error: No Makefile to build dependency /root/keystore/sell/deps/jiffy.
erlang.mk:4230: recipe for target 'deps' failed
make: *** [deps] Error 2
```

Makefile:

```
cat Makefile
PROJECT = websocket
PROJECT_DESCRIPTION = Cowboy Websocket example
PROJECT_VERSION = 1

DEPS = cowboy jiffy
dep_cowboy_commit = master

DEP_PLUGINS = cowboy

dep_jiffy = git https://github.com/davisp/jiffy

include erlang.mk

ERLC_OPTS := $(filter-out -Werror,$(ERLC_OPTS))
```

Comment: You should post the output of `make --version` and a copy of the failing rule `dep` rule from `erlang.mk`, as there's not enough info to go on here.     Typically you would get a message `no rule to make target ...` instead of `no Makefile to make dependency` which implies some custom rules or a non-standard version of make  (though I just found [this](http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2017-October/093766.html) which seems pretty similar)

Comment: make version 4.1 Running make distclean worked.. but why did I have to run distclean after I removed deps folder? This is all a fresh install of Erlang +this codebase